# IIS 7 integrated pipeline - modifying the response HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net, isapi, integrated-pipeline-mode

I'm trying to write an IIS extension that modifies the response HTML for a request as it is sent back to the client.  I know that traditionally this would be the work of an ISAPI filter however I'm a .Net developer and I've read that implementing an ISAPI filter in .Net [is a bad idea](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2009/08/03/writing-an-isapi-filter-with-net-managed-code-is-not-supported-by-microsoft.aspx).

I have read in a few places that the shiny new integrated pipeline mode of IIS 7 should now allow me to writes modules in .Net that provide the same functionality as ISAPI filters by implementing [IHttpModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttpmodule.aspx), however I can't work out how to modify the response HTML for non ASP.Net requests.

The only resource I have found on how I might do this is [this article](http://aspnetresources.com/articles/HttpFilters) however this doesn't appear to work for non ASP.Net resources or in cases where `HttpApplication.CompleteRequest` is called, even if the integrated pipeline mode is enabled.

**How can I write an IIS module in C# that allows me to modify the response html / data for *all* requests?**

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to route all your requests through the ASP.NET module.

Comment: Even if I do this the filter is ignored if `HttpApplication.CompleteRequest` is called during processing of the page - in the application I'm working on this happens fairly often.

Comment: Ok, sorry, didn't know that. Looks difficult :-(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that this is really feasable with .NET but checkout this http://aspnetresources.com/articles/CustomErrorPages esp. the part about installing the HttpModule - perhaps this is more a matter of how IIS sees your module.

Although I am with you that a .NET-ISAPI-Filter is a bad idea I would still check [this](http://filterdotnet.codeplex.com/) out to see how much impact this has in your case.

A really hard option would be to implement a local proxy (i.e. either you can write a HttpListener-based server or use a library to ease implemenation) which listens on the port(s) to be exposed and reconfigure IIS to use other ports/localhost only... this way you can filter whatever you want... although that will impact performance too IMHO.